# Как узнать технические требования моего приложения?

Tags: производительность, кроссплатформенность

Пишу диплом, в одном из пунктов ТЗ нужно указать на каких операционках сможет работать приложение, какие тех. требования нужны для работы приложения.  Откуда это узнать?

Пишу в последнем QT на windows7. Как определить для работы приложения параметры процессора, жесткого диска, обьема озу?

Comment: А покажите пожалуйста формулировку такого запроса.

Comment: 4.3. Условия эксплуатации и требования к составу
и параметрам технических средств

Для работы программы предъявляются следующие требования к составу
и параметрам технических средств:
процессор архитектуры ARM...

Comment: @Alerr это всё ? просто меня в свое время интересовал вопрос формулировки требований на программно-аппаратную среду, так и не нашел внятной формулировки.

Comment: Вроде как пока это нашел...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишите что-нибудь вроде "средней температуры по больнице" (от XP и выше). Я за все пять лет института ни разу не слышал, чтобы эти вопросы реально волновали кого-то из преподов, будь то курсовой, лабораторная или диплом. Разумеется, никто не будет на защите диплома запускать вашу программу в десятке операционных систем со специально подогнанным количеством оперативной памяти и прочими параметрами. Насколько мне известно, это требование - обычная условность, и практических целей в общем-то не несет. Я сильно удивлюсь, если кто-то из преподавателей действительно акцентирует на этом внимание. В крайнем случае уточните у препода, насколько это нужно

Comment: А как это вообще делается? как можно точно сказать какой обьем памяти нужно приложению, какой жесткий? Сидеть подсчитывать и тестить? Например на играх пишут минимальные системные требования, откуда игроделы берут эти требования?

Comment: @Alerr, они высасывают их из пальца (правда, на основе всего своего опыта).

Comment: @Alerr эмпирически. Впрочем, еще раз повторю - в 146% случаев всем по фигу на них. В дипломе есть куда более интересные для комиссии аспекты

Answer (score 4):

Открываешь диспетчер задач, смотришь на расход RAM процессом своего диплома, умножаешь на 2  - профит.
По процессору сложно сказать не видя софтину.
Операционка - зависит от заложенного уровня переносимости.

В общем, можешь написать конфигурацию своего компьютера и не переживать.

Если хочется правды и реализма - виртуальная машина в руки =)